# Myrrix java.io.IOException upon ingest when following the tutorial

Tags: myrrix

I am attempting to follow the tutorial for evaluating Myrrix for my collaborative filtering needs:
http://myrrix.com/quick-start/

On my Windows 7 laptop, I am able to get the stand-alone java binary running. I can load the web interface on port 80. However, when I go to ingest the sample audioscrobber data I get the message:

```
Error 500 : /ingest

java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location [C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1372181071432-0\work\Tomcat\localhost\_\tmp] is not valid
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2698)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2640)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1076)
at net.myrrix.web.servlets.IngestServlet.doPost(IngestServlet.java:64)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at net.myrrix.web.servlets.AbstractMyrrixServlet.service(AbstractMyrrixServlet.java:155)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I was hoping that it was just a matter of adding a "--localInputDir" directive to the command line would fix things. However, this seems unrelated to where the Tomcat server is trying to upload.

How do I modify the stand-alone binary so that I am able to successfully ingest sample data for training?

Answer (score 2):

Odd. If I follow the path in the provided error, the final 'tmp' directory is missing. If I manually add it in windows explorer and attempt to re-ingest, things appear to go as planned.

Viewing the log, it appears that the learning process has begun.

Comment: Yes this works -- I have found that in some cases the system temp directory on Windows itself was not correct. That is, `java` was globally using a temp dir that did not exist. If that's the case, setting `java.io.tmpdir` can fix that. And then, yeah, you need to make `tmp` within Tomcat's workspace. That part looks like a Tomcat bug on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of this before but not been able to reproduce it. For some reason, the temp dir that Tomcat allocates is either not actually created, or not accessible.

You can try deleting that whole directory starting with "137..." to ensure that Tomcat makes another new one. Or try investigating this path to see if you can create and/or make accessible that temp dir.

This should be controlled by Tomcat's `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` system property. You could also try setting that to somewhere else like `/tmp`.

As far as I know it's some oddness with Tomcat and Windows, but it may be transient and fixable per above.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure out a workaround for this? It has been bugging me as the tmp directory isn't created and I cannot get to change the path that Tomcat uses. Only thing that is working is to manually create the dir every time, but obviously that's not a permanent solution...

Comment: I don't have any good additional solution here. It should just be there, but isn't in some cases and I don't know why.